# socket.io showing more id than connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a challenge, each time i start my node server, socket io shows about 548 connected clients but i haven't even connected.

server side code

```
var io = require('socket.io')(webServer);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
module.exports.mws = socket;
// module.exports.io = io;
console.log(socket.id);
});
```

client side

```
var clientSocket = "";
if(clientSocket==""){
    clientSocket = io();
}
```

console log from server

pdmyQIBIhLzCGq-JAAcQ

zevbtxD6wLwobHDlAAcR

rkJNbTn3lzp9VUUFAAcS

FQoWOj_SqtCTxhPOAAcT

Y3jGL5UWRMVvtuygAAcU

mf57d9mIsquESA5mAAcV

cotbEDo9I5GxuuUWAAcW

-fr1aaMcjfBo8MM3AAcX .......

and more i don't get i know am very much knew with sockets

Comment: Can you provide more code of the client?

Comment: I worked all night and found the issue, i had set an interval that kept reconnecting, cause of poor conditioning. but thank you